# Program to count all squares in matchstick grid

Tags: algorithm, graph, tripadvisor

Design a data structure to represent the below grid formed using match sticks. Then using the data structure as an input write a program to count all the possible squares in the below example figures.
(Please navigate to below links to access the images)

[Example 1 of Match Stick Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iXFR.png)

[Example 2 of Match Stick Grid with disconnected squares](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQAjI.gif)